# Qt Signal calling from second thread works -> no effect on connected slot

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, qt

I have a Qt-Application. One of my class `ViewSimulation` has a static-Methode `loggingHandler` which calls (emit) a class-signal `logging`. The methode `loggingHandler`will be passed as function-pointer to a c-file `publisher.c`. `publisher.c` calls his function-pointer `(*logger)` in a seperate thread.

At the debugging I'm seeing `publisher.c` calls `ViewSimulation::loggingHandler` and the signals `logging` is emited, but the connected slot does not react. But if a call/emit `logging` in the main thread, the slot of `&ViewGooseList::logging)` react.

Why the slot is not reacting by "calling" from the other **c-thread** in `publisher.c`?

**ViewSimulation.cpp/h**

```
class ViewSimulation : public QGroupBox
{
...
    signals:
          void logging(int id, uint64_t timestamp);
    private:
          static void loggingHandler(int id, uint64_t timestamp);
    ViewSimulation* ViewSimulation::m_current;
...
    void ViewSimulation::loggingHandler(int id, uint64_t timestamp)
    {
          emit ViewSimulation::m_current->logging(id, timestamp);
    }
...
    connect(m_gooseSimulation, &ViewSimulation::logging, m_gooseList, &ViewGooseList::logging);
    setLogging(loggingHandler);
```

**publisher.c/h**

```
/*Header*/
void setLogging(void (*logging)(int, uint64_t));
static void (*logger)(int gooseId, uint64_t timestamp);

/*C-File*/
void setLogging(void (*logging)(int, uint64_t))
{
    logger = logging;
}
...
/*This methode will be called from main-thread **AND** from second thread */
logger(gooseMessage->id, gooseMessage->lastTimeStamp);
...
```

Comment: What happens if you explicitly create a queued connection: `connect(m_gooseSimulation, &ViewSimulation::logging, m_gooseList, &ViewGooseList::logging, Qt::QueuedConnection);`

Comment: @NikosC. Now it seems to work. Thx.

Comment: @NikosC. strange behaviour cause default connection type is AutoConnection that determinates if the object in other thread or not, and if so - uses QueuedConnection automatically.

Comment: @someoneinthebox It is strange. But I've run into this issue myself a couple of times. I don't know why `Qt::AutoConnection` fails with certain connections :-/ Maybe when the object for which the signal is emitted was moved to a QThread but the `emit` happens on behalf of that object from a different thread, then it fails. Or maybe the object was not moved to a QThread but it is used from a thread. Then I guess it would fail too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For signal/slot connections across threads, you should create queued connections:

```
connect(m_gooseSimulation, &ViewSimulation::logging, m_gooseList,
        &ViewGooseList::logging, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```